# Proof by contradiction on if and only if statements

Tags: proof-writing

Suppose I want to prove a general statement like 'A is true if and only if B is true'

If I assumed B is untrue and showed that subsequently A is untrue, which direction am I actually proving? I guess it is the direction going from left to right?

Comment: Correct.  Proving that $\neg B\implies \neg A$ is equivalent to proving that $A\implies B$.  Assuming you finished that step, then what remains to prove the bi-implication is to prove $B\implies A$ or to prove $\neg A\implies \neg B$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you for clearing up on this!

Comment: @JMoravitz isn't that an answer (rather than a comment)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly. If you assumed that $B$ is untrue, and proved that $A$ is then untrue, you have proven the statement $\neg B\implies \neg A$. This statement is logically equivalent to the statement $A\implies B$, which means you proved the direction from left to right.

You still have to prove either $B\implies A$ or its equivalent, $\neg A\implies \neg B$.